# What is difference between self.view.frame and self.superview.frame and how to use them?

Tags: iphone, cgrect, device-orientation

I would like to know that what is difference between these both lines of code?

```
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 900);
```

and I want to change the view frame when my orientation will change, because it will change the position of labels, and I want them in middle of screen, can anyone guide me ?

I am using following delegate method, for orientation, but it is not working with

```
self.view.frame
```

but it is working ok with following line

```
self.view.superview.frame
```

See the following code

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation     {

// Return YES for supported orientations
//return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    NSLog(@"LEFT");
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 480, 320);
    NSLog(@"Show self.view.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
   // self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(-50, -70, 800, 900);
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(340, 320, 100, 30)];
}
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"RIGHT");
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    NSLog(@"Show self.view.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
         //self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 90, 800, 900); //It is working if           I will uncomment it
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 300, 100, 30)];
}
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    //self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 900);//It is working if           I will uncomment it
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 400, 100, 30)];    
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.view` is the view of self (if we are talking about viewControllers).
`self.view.superview` is the view that is holding `self.view`.

So, in short, if you add a view to the window the superview of that view will be the window.

Setting the frame will fail if the autoresize mask isn't set correctly.

Comment: but why self.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 480, 320);
  NSLog(@"Show self.view.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
This is not working with my orientation?

Comment: Nothing is changing I am changing the self.view.frame, but if I will change the self.view.superview.frame, then it is changing the rect, why?

Comment: Don't know with out seeing all your code, it's just going to be guess work. But it could be the views autoresize mask?

Comment: See the code now, I have edited it with real problem that I am facing

Answer (score 0):

As a generic statement, the first line is trying set the frame of the current viewController's view that this code is written in.

The second line is trying to set the frame of the **parent view** of the view of the current viewController's view.

What this exactly means, and which one you should be using I'm afraid depends on the view hierarchy you have set up in your application.

Comment: I am changing the self.view.frame, but it is not working,but at the same time, I am using the superview frame, then it is working, why?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing much about your apps implementation, but perhaps the self.view.superview is the UIView which is actually displayed on screen to the user at this point.

Comment: I have edited the question, now see the orientation code, can you understand the problem?